# HTML/CSS Formatting Issues

Tags: html, css

I am working on an assignment that is giving me grief. I am supposed to make a red box that matches the color of an image. This box is supposed to be centered on the page. The box is supposed to be 80% of the page. The image is supposed to be inside the box. The image is supposed to be 80% width of the BOX it sits in. The image is to be centered vertically. I am trying to do this using CSS. Here is my code. What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://blackhawks.nhl.com/">
                        <img src="http://www.wallpaperpimper.com/wallpaper/Hockey/Chicago_Blackhawks/Chicago-Blackhawks-Blackhawks-Logo-1-JPS6RQXFBC-1024x768.jpg">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.box  {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #dd111;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
} 
.box ul {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.box ul li {
    width: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Any reason it is in a list? The list itself with out a reset is going to mess up your alignment.

Comment: Well I am using a List because I am going to have to place 2 box stripes inside the box...one above the image and one below...but inside the red box.

Comment: Geeze, settle with the downvotes. Its marked as a homework question and he obviously is new.

Comment: To be fair to the downvoters, they did vote prior to me adding the homework tag.

Comment: So are the 2 box stripes borders?

Comment: I guess they would be considered borders. They are in-between the image and the bottom of the box..so they would have a margin.

Comment: Okay, well I updated my answer. Maybe it will give you some more ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list isn't necessary you could do this. If you want to use a list you need to set the ul padding and margin to 0.

```
 <style type="text/css">

    .box {
       width:80%;
       margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    }

    img {
       width:80%;
       margin:0 auto 0 auto;
       display:block;
    }

   .box-stripe {
       width:80%;
       height:15px; 
       margin:0 auto 0 auto;
   }

    </style>


    <body>

    <div class="box">

    <div class="box-stripe"></div>

    <img src="yourimage.png" alt="" />

    <div class="box-stripe"></div>

    </div>

    </body>
```

Or if you prefer the list you could do something like this. It should get you close anyways.

```
<style type="text/javascript">

.box {
width:80%;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

.box ul {
width:80%;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
padding:0px;
display:block; /*may not need to do this but I don't think a UL is a block element */
}

.box ul .box-stripe {
width:100%;
display:block;
height:15px;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

.box ul .img {
width:100%;
display:block;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

</style>



      <body>

            <div class="box">

            <ul>

             <li>class="box-stripe"></li>

             <li class="img"><img src="yourimage.png" alt="" /></li>

             <li class="box-stripe"></li>

           </ul>

            </div>

       </body>
```

Every browser treats HTML elements differently in terms of padding, margin, line height, ect. This is why I recommend a CSS reset. And most UL's have some padding by default.

Comment: I will revise to try to match what you are doing.

Comment: The problem is the stripes aren't showing up but if I modify the code, it displays the stripes with the width of the box, and I cannot move the black stripes down to overlap on the picture.

Comment: Do you have a URL or a jsfiddle that I could maybe look at? Or maybe re-post your current code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need the `ul` and `li` for some reason, but the main thing you are missing is that the `img` is not given a width.

If an `img` does not have a width it will use the native width of the image and stretch its container.  In the case of your current html (with the `ul`) you would need to give the image a width of 100% since the `li` is already set to `80%`.

Comment: Well I am using a List because I am going to have to place 2 box stripes inside the box...one above the image and one below...but inside the red box.

Comment: @YoungGuy - remember that you can color borders too. So you may be able to create your stripes using those instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on borders (or use Firebug or Chrome developer tools to inspect your elements). With borders on I think it becomes a lot more obvious why things are not positioned as you think they are.

http://jsfiddle.net/2vWY3/1/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it, although I'm not sure if the box needs to be 80 or 100% of the *height* of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/ZLUGg/2/

I changed the box color and the image size for testing/demonstration. Makes it easier to develop too.